# git tf pull Could not find a valid TFS Collection at

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

Im trying to get GIT-TF to work with our 2012 TFS repo (not a git tfs repo!). I keep getting an error when i try to pull : *Could not find a valid TFS Collection at http://MYSERVER:8080/DefaultCollection*

To set up i used :

**git tf configure --force http://MYSERVER:8080/DefaultCollection $\testfolder**

(testfolder is already in the TFS repo and on local disk)

I did try using **$/testfolder**, but got an error saying the path must be absolute. Seems it would only accept with / or \. Either way, i still get the same error when i try and pull.

Any one got any ideas ? (cos im all out of them!)

Answer (score 1):

Seems the command to configure should have been :

git tf configure --force http://MYSERVER:8080/**tfs**/DefaultCollection $\testfolder

doh...